# Querying mysql based on date 

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query on sql (mysql) based on the date.

Something like:

```
Select * from table_name where e_date > 2001-12-30;
```

What is the right query?

I am not able to pen down my problem and get the right response from google.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this query? It seems to be correct with quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, you'll need to put the date around single quotes though.

Answer (score 2):

Just add closing quotes on your date.

```
Select * from table_name where e_date > '2001-12-30'
```

Check the link below:

[Date and Time Functions in MYsQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

This Site will help you out regarding date time functions

Regards

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Select * 
from table_name 
where e_date > DATE('2001-12-30');
```